# Torn screen in fresh new Lubuntu installation

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, firefox, gpu-driver

I have just installed lubuntu and my screen goes weird. The torn screen lasts for few seconds and mostly occurs on much moving screens like browser with YouTube site.

[image]

I have Desktop PC with AMD Ryzen 5 3400G Vega 11 and gigabyte board.

Edit1: Now after using Ubuntu a while I realized it only happens with app Firefox. Is something wrong with it?

Edit2: Using Chrome also chreates tearing. Got used to it now :(

[image]

Comment: Is there something interesting in the log files? It might be a driver problem.

Comment: Providing details about the release of Lubuntu would have been helpful. My guess looking at screen is you're using LXQt thus 19.10 or 20.04? but it's best if we're not guessing. Have you used proprietary drivers? (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.3/software_sources.html) but I don't know your release details (thus software stack, kernel etc) so won't look further.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu. @guiverc guessed it right, using LXQt 20.04 latest. Kernel: 5.4.0-37-generic.

Comment: @wie5Ooma where can I find logs?

Comment: @wie5Ooma I googled and found to look in /var/log/, can you guide me specifically.

Comment: Is there something in syslog? And as guiverc asked before: Are you using or have you used proprietary drivers?

Comment: @wie5Ooma sorry for late post, My system does not have attached external graphic card. I am solely depended on AMD® Ryzen 5 3400g with radeon vega graphics × 8. I have also switched from Lubuntu to ubuntu which reduced such tearing but it still occurs on browser sometimes or on some specific apps. Firstly I thought its because of firefox browser hence switched to chrome but still chrome also shows such behaviour. Once I switch between apps it gets corrected (torn screen gone). I have not installed any specific drivers rather than only ubuntu system update.

Comment: On Lubuntu/LXQt you can switch to OpenGL (hardware accelerated rendering) instead of the default X Render - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.16/window_effects.html

Comment: @guiverc While I was on Lubuntu I tried that as well. but don't think that helped me. Currently on ubuntu. Will search if such option available.

Comment: 11:31:54 AM gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
11:31:49 AM bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
11:31:46 AM kernel: kfd kfd: device 1002:15d8 NOT added due to errors
11:31:46 AM kernel: scsi 9:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
11:31:46 AM kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
11:31:46 AM kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
11:31:46 AM kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Comment: important marked logs after starting ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue was occurred in Ubuntu but with less occurrence when I was using Ubuntu 20.04.1 ([Link](https://askubuntu.com/q/1279084/1097300)). I think there was some issue in core OS. After installing newer version Ubuntu 20.04.2 the issue is gone.

Comment: FYI:   Lubuntu 20.04.2 installs with the HWE stack, so you could have enabled that on your last install too.  The newer stack also includes newer kernel modules (aka. *drivers*)

Comment: I am bit new to Ubuntu hence don't understand the terms but thanks. May help for future visitors.

Comment: This is written in hopes it's educational/informative.  20.04 was released with the 5.4 kernel and all kernel modules for that release (kernel module is better known as *driver*).  20.10 released with the 5.8 kernel (thus later kernel modules or *drivers*) and was available to 20.04 with 20.04.2 using HWE... You needed later kernel modules (ie. *drivers* available with a later kernel).  For details maybe see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack  Ubuntu & Lubuntu have same stack just run different desktop software on top..

Comment: Well done for working it out though :)  (Installations with 20.04, or 20.04.1 media default to using GA stack, installs made with 20.04.2 or later media default to using HWE kernel stack for Lubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop always defaults to HWE unlike prior releases)... though on both you can opt to change to other stack post-install; see wiki links I provided)