# Screen render error in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, hardware

I have also asked same question earlier (thinking it was screen tearing) but did not got solution.

Screenshots of issues:
[image]

[image]

My specs:

[image]

All system up to date with latest ubuntu 20.04. No additional hardware (Graphic card and all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue occurred in Lubuntu but with more occurrences ([Link](https://askubuntu.com/q/1252264/1097300)). I think there was some issue with the core OS or drivers. After installing the newer version of Ubuntu 20.04.2 the issue is gone.